# What software should I use to restrict traffic on my LAN?

Tags: windows, routing, traffic

I would like to use restrict network traffic on my LAN at home. I have one laptop and one PC. I use D-Link 502T router (it does not have many functions). 
I have started to work with squid but I don't think it will fit my needs. 
I just would like to block particular websites etc. (maybe block some ports).
I use Windows 7 just in case that relevant.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For blocking internet traffic, I would suggest using [OpenDNS](http://opendns.com). I've used them for several years now to restrict content on my network. There is no charge for most of their services. Blocking ports would be best handled at the router level as well. The Dlink router can use [OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dsl-502t-genii) to replace the default firmware. This would provide you with more configuration options and certainly allow you to block ports.

Comment: I will give OpenDNS a try but as I have looked into OpenWRT i am afraid of 'bricking' my router - even though it's an old one:)

Comment: I can understand the concern about bricking your router. Typically if the service isn't available on your network somewhere, blocking the incoming port isn't necessary. Now if you want to block outgoing traffic on specific ports that may be a bit more difficult with the OEM firmware.

Comment: Also you could use an application firewall such as Comodo to block outgoing ports on an individual computer.

Comment: I am actually using Comodo on my laptop but I am looking for something that can allow me to restrict the traffic on whole LAN. I have heard that I can transform my laptop into a router. Anybody familiar with doing such a thing  ?

Comment: Your laptop would have to be on constantly (and in the house) in order to serve as a router. You are likely going to spend more time working on getting your laptop to serve as a router than it takes to buy a used Linksys WRT54G and put TomatoUSB or DD-WRT on it.